# What is the regular expression to get a token of a URL?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Say I have strings like these:

```
bunch of other html<a href="http://domain.com/133742/The_Token_I_Want.zip" more html and stuff
bunch of other html<a href="http://domain.com/12345/another_token.zip" more html and stuff
bunch of other html<a href="http://domain.com/0981723/YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN.zip" more html and stuff
```

What is the regular expression to match `The_Token_I_Want`, `another_token`, `YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN`?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. What platform are you on? Can there be more than one subdirectory?

Comment: Backtrack from the string end:
    /([^\/]+)\..+$/

Comment: The regex will run in javascript?

Comment: I'm using C++ with `boost::regex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appendix B of [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) gives a doozy of a regular expression for splitting a URI into its components, and we can adapt it for your case

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*/([^.]+)[^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
                                     #######
```

This leaves `The_Token_I_Want` in `$6`, which is the “hashderlined” subexpression above. (Note that the hashes are not part of the pattern.) See it live:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$_ = "http://domain.com/133742/The_Token_I_Want.zip";    
if (m!^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*/([^.]+)[^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?!) {
  print "$6\n";
}
else {
  print "no match\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./prog.pl
The_Token_I_Want
```

**UPDATE:** I see in a comment that you're using [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), so remember to escape the backslash in your C++ program.

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  boost::regex token("^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*"
                     "/([^.]+)"
                   //  ####### I CAN HAZ HASHDERLINE PLZ
                     "[^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?");

  const char * const urls[] = {
    "http://domain.com/133742/The_Token_I_Want.zip",
    "http://domain.com/12345/another_token.zip",
    "http://domain.com/0981723/YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN.zip",
  };

  BOOST_FOREACH(const char *url, urls) {
    std::cout << url << ":\n";

    std::string t;
    boost::cmatch m;
    if (boost::regex_match(url, m, token))
      t = m[6];
    else
      t = "<no match>";

    std::cout << "  - " << m[6] << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
http://domain.com/133742/The_Token_I_Want.zip:
  - The_Token_I_Want
http://domain.com/12345/another_token.zip:
  - another_token
http://domain.com/0981723/YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN.zip:
  - YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN
```

Comment: wouldn't that be a little overkill to just get one component?

Comment: Overkill or not, I vote for "hashderlined" to be added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

/(?:f|ht)tps?:/{2}(?:www.)?domain[^/]+.([^/]+).([^/]+)/i

or

/\w{3,5}:/{2}(?:w{3}.)?domain[^/]+.([^/]+).([^/]+)/i

Answer (score 1):

```
/a href="http://domain.com/[0-9]+/([a-zA-Z_]+).zip"/
```

Might want to add more characters to [a-zA-Z_]+

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(http|ftp)+://[[:alnum:]./_]+/([[:alnum:]._-]+).[[:alnum:]_-]+
```

**(**`[[:alnum:]._-]+`**)** is a group for the matched pattern, and in your example its value will be `The_Token_I_Want`. to access this group, use \2 or $2, because **(**`http|ftp`**)** is the first group and **(**`[[:alnum:]._-]+`**)** is the second group of the matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First, use an HTML parser and get a DOM. Then get the anchor elements and loop over them looking for the hrefs. Don't try to grab the token straight out of a string.

Then:

The glib answer would be:

```
/(The_Token_I_Want.zip)/
```

You might want to be a little more precise then a single example.

I'm guessing you are actually looking for:

```
/([^/]+)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m/The_Token_I_Want/
```

You'll have to be more specific about what kind of token it is. A number? A string? Does it repeat? Does it have a form or pattern to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to use something smarter than a RegEx.  For example, if you're using C# you could use the System.Uri class to parse it for you.